# Attached functions not working in cloned elements

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, clone

I am trying clone a div with two text inputs in it and using `wpColorPicker()` to convert then in a colorpicker. If I bind the function on document ready, the cloned items got converted in color picker, but not opening up.

If I set it so that it triggers after clone, it works on cloned elements, but not on the existing elements. And, if I use `true` on `.clone()`'s `withDataAndEvents`, the color picker gets added twice for each elements where the first one doesn't open but the second one works.

Here are some of the codes I tried..

```
<div class="colors">
    <input type="text" class="tabs-bg form-control" value="#fe4641">
    <input type="text" class="tabs-color form-control" value="#ffffff">
</div>
<button id="add-tab">Add Tab</button>
<button id="remove-tab" disabled="disabled">Remove Tab</button>
```

This one adds the non-working color picker in cloned elements..

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    $('.tabs-bg, .tabs-col').wpColorPicker();

    $( '#add-tab' ).click(function() {
        var tabdiv = $('.colors:first').clone();
        tabdiv.hide().insertAfter('.colors:last').slideDown('fast', function(){

        var afterAdd = $('.colors').length;
            if ( afterAdd >= 2 ) {
                $('#remove-tab').removeAttr('disabled');
            }
        });

        return false;
    });

    $( '#remove-tab' ).click(function() {
        $('.colors:last').slideUp('fast',function(){
            $(this).remove();
            var afterRemove = $('.colors').length;
            if ( afterRemove < 2 ) {
                $('#remove-tab').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
            }
        });
        return false;
    });

});
```

This one adds working color picker to cloned elements..

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){

    $( '#add-tab' ).click(function() {
        var tabdiv = $('.colors:first').clone();
        tabdiv.hide().insertAfter('.colors:last').slideDown('fast', function(){
        $(this).find('.tabs-bg, .tabs-col').wpColorPicker();
        var afterAdd = $('.colors').length;
            if ( afterAdd >= 2 ) {
                $('#remove-tab').removeAttr('disabled');
            }
        });

        return false;
    });

    $( '#remove-tab' ).click(function() {
        $('.colors:last').slideUp('fast',function(){
            $(this).remove();
            var afterRemove = $('.colors').length;
            if ( afterRemove < 2 ) {
                $('#remove-tab').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
            }
        });
        return false;
    });

});
```

And, this one adds two color picker for each element..

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    $('.tabs-bg, .tabs-col').wpColorPicker();

    $( '#add-tab' ).click(function() {
        var tabdiv = $('.colors:first').clone(true);
        tabdiv.hide().insertAfter('.colors:last').slideDown('fast', function(){
        var afterAdd = $('.colors').length;
            if ( afterAdd >= 2 ) {
                $('#remove-tab').removeAttr('disabled');
            }
        });

        return false;
    });

    $( '#remove-tab' ).click(function() {
        $('.colors:last').slideUp('fast',function(){
            $(this).remove();
            var afterRemove = $('.colors').length;
            if ( afterRemove < 2 ) {
                $('#remove-tab').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
            }
        });
        return false;
    });

});
```

What I am doing wrong? What should do to get only a single working color picker for each cloned elements? Please help

Comment: Yeah, tried that also. No luck though.

Comment: @Sushil That doesn't change anything. The latter is simply the shorthand way of binding the click event.

Comment: hmm.. let me create a fiddle.

Comment: it seems there's no cdn for wpColorPicker.

Comment: @Sushil nope!! It comes bundled with WordPress only.

Comment: can you try creating those elements dynamically in the first place in the ready event? so instead of `<input type="text" class="tabs-bg form-control" value="#fe4641">` being present in the html, can you try creating it in the `document.ready` event and hook the wpColorPicker to it?

Comment: @Sushil Yeah, I tried that also. Same result. please check this fiddle, I have used jQuery Slider in place of wpColorPicker. You can see the issue in cloned elements. http://jsfiddle.net/itsabhik/nLovyaxv/4/

Comment: can you check this fiddle @Abhik http://jsfiddle.net/nLovyaxv/5/ and let me know if it works for you?

Comment: so in your case you need to remove the element instead of hiding it and then call the `wpColorPicker` again

Comment: this should work for you. `$('#add-tab').click(function() {
    var tabdiv = $('.colors:first').clone(true);
    tabdiv.remove().insertAfter('.colors:last').slideDown('fast', function() {
        var afterAdd = $('.colors').length;
        if (afterAdd >= 2) {
            $('#remove-tab').removeAttr('disabled');
        }
    });

   $('.tabs-bg, .tabs-col').wpColorPicker();
    return false;
});`

Comment: @Sushil it indeed is working in fiddle, however, not in my actual case. It duplicates each colorpicker in cloned elements. Is there any way I can remove that `wpColorPicker()` function in cloned elements so that I can add them right after they are added?

Comment: did you try my other comment?

Comment: @Sushil, yes buddy. :(

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/88411/discussion-between-sushil-and-abhik).